# Windows mobile button text new line

Tags: c#, windows-mobile

I need to have new line in button.text in Windows Mobile 6,5. I have following code

```
this.button1.Text = "some \r\n one";
```

Even if I try

```
this.button1.Text = "some" + Enviroment.NewLine + "one";
```

I can't see second line in my button. I see only some. I tried to resize my button but It doesn't effect on it.
Any Ideas?
Thanks

Comment: I don't have property AutoSize in my button properties... I don't know why...

Comment: oho i think `button` has no `autosize` property,,sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Button control does not support Multiline input.

Comment: I dont think so. Iam rewritting code from visual basic to C# and app written by visual basic allow multiple input, but i dont know how rewrite the code to c#

Comment: I'm going with a wild guess here, but you could try HTML stuff like `<br/>`. I don't know what code the buttons use.

Answer (score 0):

Compact Framework does not support multiline text (BS_MULTILINE) although it is supported by C/C++: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775951%28v=vs.85%29.aspx.

You may use this solution: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vssmartdevicesvbcs/thread/67664186-e61c-4510-8414-939fce37a30c

Answer (score 0):

The better way is to use a image in which you have the TEXT.
Instead of the button use a picture box and add the codes to the click event of picture box.